# Error loading workspace in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Whenewer I try to open Eclipse, i keep getting the same error. When I check ..\workspace.metadata.log, this is what I get:

```
    !SESSION 2016-06-15 09:26:59.256 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.5.2.M20160212-1500
java.version=1.8.0_91
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=it_IT
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-06-15 09:27:11.199
!MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.resources (84).
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.core.resources.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:792)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:721)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:941)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.sources.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Incompatible file format. Workspace was saved with an incompatible version: 0.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.WorkspaceTreeReader.getReader(WorkspaceTreeReader.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.WorkspaceTreeReader.getReader(WorkspaceTreeReader.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.restoreTree(SaveManager.java:1054)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.restore(SaveManager.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.startup(SaveManager.java:1588)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.startup(Workspace.java:2386)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.open(Workspace.java:2157)
    at org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start(ResourcesPlugin.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:764)
    ... 29 more
Root exception:
org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Incompatible file format. Workspace was saved with an incompatible version: 0.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.WorkspaceTreeReader.getReader(WorkspaceTreeReader.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.WorkspaceTreeReader.getReader(WorkspaceTreeReader.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.restoreTree(SaveManager.java:1054)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.restore(SaveManager.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.startup(SaveManager.java:1588)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.startup(Workspace.java:2386)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.open(Workspace.java:2157)
    at org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start(ResourcesPlugin.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:764)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:721)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:941)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.sources.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-06-15 09:27:11.350
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/resources/IContainer
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.resources (84).
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.sources.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.core.resources.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:792)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:721)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:941)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Incompatible file format. Workspace was saved with an incompatible version: 0.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.WorkspaceTreeReader.getReader(WorkspaceTreeReader.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.WorkspaceTreeReader.getReader(WorkspaceTreeReader.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.restoreTree(SaveManager.java:1054)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.restore(SaveManager.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.startup(SaveManager.java:1588)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.startup(Workspace.java:2386)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.open(Workspace.java:2157)
    at org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start(ResourcesPlugin.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:764)
    ... 29 more
```

I have tried deleting the workspace, and it didn't fix the problem. I tried to look for some .snap files, but I didn't find any of them. I even tried deleting Eclipse and downloading it again, but I keep getting this error.

Comment: by deleting the workspace did it ask you to create a new one? it continues even with a new workspace?

Comment: Go to your <workspace>/.metadata/.plugins folder and delete the org.eclipse.core.resources folder

Some corruption must have happened in your workspace. Just follow the above step and it should work

Comment: he said that he tried deleting the workspace and it didnt fix the problem so i guess he delete all the .metatada folder.

Comment: Yup, as @Apostolos pointed out, i already tried deleting the whole workspace, and it didn't solved my problem. Deleting the workspace simply cause Eclipse to re-create the same workspace, in the same position.

Comment: if you try to create a workspace in a different folder, does it do the same?

Answer (score 7):

Maybe your workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.root/*.tree has been corrupted.

Delete the *.tree file and open the workspace in eclipse and re import the projects in the workspace.

This solution worked for me .

Answer (score 2):

remove the folder org.eclipse.core.resources that located under plugins on the same place where the log file is.

Answer (score 0):

Trying [the -clean command line option](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2013/08/22/eclipse-command-line-options/) is always a good idea. With bundle errors, that can often fix the problem. For example:

eclipse.exe -clean

It's only needed once, as it slows down the start-up.

Comment: Sorry about that. A clean start is always worth a try. check out Apostolos's latest comment under your question for another suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

After some updates suddenly my dbeaver was not opening, to fix it ,
i went to below location
C:\Users\NikhilKamani\AppData\Roaming\DBeaverData\workspace6

and deleted metadata folder and started dbeaver again and it worked

Note: If you delete metadata you will have to add driver again when you try to access your databse.